# how to set excel cell format in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm modifying an existing application written in vb.net. 
There is an export option which exports information to an excel sheet.
Before exporting the cell format is defined as follows.

```
.Cells(cRow, 17).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00_);($#,##0.00)"
```

this works fine. But according to the new requirement, currency symbol is dynamic.
Therefore once I set the currency (eg : Malaysian riggit -MYR),

```
.Cells(cRow, 17).NumberFormat = "MYR#,##0.00_);(MYR#,##0.00)"
```

this gives an error "**Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class**".
there can be many currencies and I tried setting the currency using a variable.

```
Dim strCurrency As String = ""
strCurrency = "SGD"
.Cells(cRow, 17).NumberFormat = ""+strCurrency +"#,##0.00_);("+strCurrency +"#,##0.00)"
```

All are giving me the same error.
Someone please let me know how to set the custom currency symbol.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken any characters in an EXCEL numeric format must be enclosed in quotation marks so:

```
Dim strCurrency As String = ""
strCurrency = "SGD"
.Cells(cRow, 17).NumberFormat = """"+strCurrency +"""#,##0.00_);("""+strCurrency +"""#,##0.00)"
```

Comment: You are correct .it's not a mistake. Your code works nicely .thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
.Cells(cRow, 17).NumberFormat = strCurrency & "#,##0.00_);(" & strCurrency & "#,##0.00)"
```

There is no need to use so many quotes as shown in the answer that is accepted.

**Explanation**

Your string

`"MYR#,##0.00_);(MYR#,##0.00)"`

can also be written as

`"MYR" & "#,##0.00_);(" & "MYR" & "#,##0.00)"`

Now simply replace `"MYR"` with your variable

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the currency symbol inside quotation :

```
Dim strCurrency = Chr(34) & "SGD" & Chr(34)
.Cells(cRow, 17).NumberFormat = String.Format("{0}#,##0.00_);({0}#,##0.00)", strCurrency)
```

The `Chr(34)` = `"`

Comment: Please provide an explanation as well.